# Software for building DOM/CSS-class references

Tags: css, dom

I am currently setting CSS class names in a quite large browser-based application. I started sketching out the HTML element layout (basically a large set of nested boxes) on paper, and writing down the CSS style name next to each box.

This is of course very tedious, and I started to realize that this would be very useful in the application documentation (the one we have now is just a long list of the classnames with a small description for each).

Is anyone aware of any software that would be suitable for this?

Answer (score 0):

Well you **could** use MS Visio, But the best thing I find for doing this use just to have a well commented CSS file, I usually sort a bare-bones layout in HTML first, then use [CSSEdit](http://macrabbit.com/cssedit/) to style this layout into what I had originally sketched out, just making sure to add `/* Comment Here */` under each class name.